# conditional validation in jquery

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate

I am having two methods to validate the zipcode.

I am having country list box, Here if i select usa i need to validate using   **usazipRegex** method or if i selects canada i need to validate using **canadazipRegex** . suppose i selects any other country just i need **required**

```
//USA zipcode validation methode 
jQuery.validator.addMethod("usazipRegex", function(value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || /^[0-9]{5}(?:-[0-9]{4})?$/i.test(value);
    }, "You must enter your postal code in this format: #####-####");


//Canada zipcode validation methode 
jQuery.validator.addMethod("canadazipRegex", function(value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || /^[ABCEGHJ-NPRSTVXY]{1}[0-9]{1}[ABCEGHJ-NPRSTV-Z]{1}[ ]?[0-9]{1}[ABCEGHJ-NPRSTV-Z]{1}[0-9]{1}$/i.test(value);
    }, "You must enter your postal code in this format: A#A  #A#");
```

validation plugin
http://bassistance.de/

How can i do this.Suggest me !

Answer (score 1):

You can toggle a CSS `class` on the input when changing the country and then use [`addClassRules( name, rules )`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/addClassRules#namerules), as in:

```
jQuery.validator.addClassRules("usa", {
  required: true,
  minlength: 10,
  usazipRegex: true
});

jQuery.validator.addClassRules("canada", {
  required: true,
  minlength: 8,
  canadaPostalCodeRegex: true
});
```

Combine with `jQuery.validator.addMethod` to add your custom validators `usazipRegex` and `canadaPostalCodeRegex`.

Comment: what about other country ! can u explain .should i add the class usa and canada to list box